# Python smtpd DebuggingServer. How do I know it is running correctly?

Tags: python, smtpd

I'm testing a Flask app emailing capability with Python's smptd DebuggingServer with:
`python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:8025`
and alternatively
`python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n localhost:8025`

These commands don't provide any feedback at all; seem to freeze the program. Control-C won't even do anything. Is there something wrong with my smtpd module? How can I tell if it is actually running?

Python 3.9.10.
Windows 11. Terminal is CMD

EDIT: Also, no dummy email dump is happening in the console. I have verified that the email sending capability of my app is working.

Comment: It turns out that it actually works. It's just a matter of setting the proper environment variables for MAIL_SERVER and MAIL_PORT.